# How to get the position in an actor inside a table with LIBGDX?

Tags: java, libgdx

Well the title says it all, I want to get the position of an actor inside a table

```
Button button = new Button(bs);
table.add(button).width(50).height(50);
table.top().center();
```

By using

```
button.localToStageCoordinates(new Vector2(button.getX(), button.getY()));
```

I get a near position but not exact, here is an screenshot, red squares are the positions I'm getting, while the transparent squares are the buttons.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I manage to do it like this:

> button.localToParentCoordinates(new Vector2(table.getX(),
>   table.getY()));